# What is is the best way to manage edit/destroy/new links with authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization, crud

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to create a standard CRUD rails application for displaying text posts. It's pretty similar to blog where I would like authenticated users to be able to edit and destroy posts while visitors to the site can just see and browse the existing posts.

I would like to know what is the best way to manage this. So far I've been using two controllers the first has a before_filter so that each route requires authentication and the associated views have edit/destroy/new links. The second controller has no authentication filter and the views don't have links to edit or destroy the posts.

This solution works, but I don't think it's very DRY. I have a feeling that if stick with this situation things will get more and more complicated as I add more functionality. Is there a better way to manage this? I'm sure it must be common problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give lockdown a try: http://stonean.com/page/lockdown

> **Lockdown is an authorization system for RubyOnRails (ver 2.x). It is
>   designed to handle a simple public vs
>   private configuration to very fine
>   grained access controls.**

Comment: Thanks. I looked at this then followed links to padlock and acl9. I think these sort of libraries are exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan talks about this problem (RY by having admin controllers and regular user controllers) and a better solution in [Railscast #19](http://railscasts.com/episodes/19-where-administration-goes).

As an aside, I hope your second controller (the one without an authorization `before_filter`) doesn't have update or destroy actions.  Even if you don't have the links in your view an unscrupulous person could create a request that would mess with your data.

Comment: Thank you for this link it really helped me understand the difference between authentication and authorization. I had never heard of this before.

Comment: @Michael Barton: No problem...always happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I use role_requirement to control user access to given controller methods via "admin" and "user" roles. I use a hand rolled lib to make sure that a given user has permission to access/manipulate specific data. So for example, if you don't "own" a certain post (say #3), yet you try to drop its ID in /posts/destroy/3, you will get shut out.